# How to enable automatic Dead letter exchange/topic creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud stream with functional beans (supplier,consumer,function) and I am interested in setting up an auxiliary regular listener of my choice (kafka/rabbit) for processing dead letter messages.

i have the below properties set which set up this microservices connections to the message bus (in my case rabbit):

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.myFunctionBean-in-0=input
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.myFunctionBean-out-0output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=my-listening-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=my-app-identifier
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=topic-i-publish-to
```

It would be really nice if the solution works with sleuth/micrometer tracing also.

Comment: Isn't spring cloud streams being deprecated?

Comment: doesnt seem to be - https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream

Comment: No it is not. Just the legacy annotations. There’s a section in the rabbit binder docs about consuming from the DLQ.

Comment: @DaveAnkin what is your question?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Hi! Thanks for reading these. I was hoping to to find a property I could set so that SCS would auto-create the DLQ (exchange) and send failures there. (I am assuming that if i manually create the DLQ myself, it will send failures there - not sure if this correct - but my employer wants me to move from SCS to SCDataflow, which means my exchange names might be dynamic, and this means DLQ handling will be even more important to automate)

Comment: worst comes to worst, I can just autowire the AmqpTemplate into my service and wrap all public entrypoints in a try catch which sends messages to a DLQ myself (in all the applications)

Comment: You mean `autoBindDlq` as one of the consumer properties - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.5-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-reference. There are more DLQ related properties depending on the level of configuration you want

Comment: oh, wow - yeah, not sure how i missed that but that looks like it does what i was looking to do